# Atribuição de objetos em Python

Tags: python, orientação-a-objetos, python-3.x

Alguém pode me dizer porque na primeira iteração a atribuição `retangulo=retangulo()` dá certo, mas na segunda não?

Aparece esse erro no Pycharm:

> <<'retangulo' object is not callable>>

Código:

```
from MDvalidateDATA import validateDATA

class ponto:

    def __init__(self,x=0,y=0):

        self.x=x

        self.y=y

class retangulo:

    def __init__(self):
        self.base=validateDATA("Digite a o valor da base(entre 1 1000): ",1000,1,"float")

        self.altura = validateDATA("Digite a o valor da altura(entre 1 1000): ", 1000, 1, "float")

    def centro(self,ponto):

        ponto.x=self.base/2

        ponto.y=self.altura/2


x="1"

while x=="1":

    retangulo=retangulo()

    ponto=ponto()

    retangulo.centro(ponto)

    print(ponto.x,ponto.y)

    x=input("Digite 1 para continuar ou quaklquer outra tecla pra sair: ")
```

Comment: Deu certo, mano :) Muito obrigado

Answer (score 1):

> Alguém pode me dizer porque na primeira iteração a atribuição
>   `retangulo = retangulo()` dá certo, mas na segunda não?

Porque na primeira iteração o nome da classe é sobrescrito com uma instância da própria classe, na segunda iteração a [instância](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#instance-objects) da classe é sobrescrita novamente com [`NoneType`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html#None), veja:

```
class ponto:
    def __init__(self):
        print ("Instância inicializada!")

    def __call__(self):
        print ("Instância foi chamada como função!")


print (type(ponto())) # <class '__main__.ponto'>
ponto = ponto()       # sobrescreve o nome da classe com uma instância de ponto 
print (type(ponto))   # <class '__main__.ponto'>
print (type(ponto())) # <class 'NoneType'>

# <class '__main__.ponto'>
# <class '__main__.ponto'>
# Instância foi chamada como função!
# <class 'NoneType'>
```

Para resolver isso altere o nome da variável para outra coisa, por exemplo `p` ou `pt`:

```
pt = ponto()

print (type(pt))      # <class '__main__.ponto'>
print (type(ponto())) # <class '__main__.ponto'>
```

Uma outra forma é alterar o nome da classe, se preferir seguir a [**convenção**](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names), a letra inicial do nome deve ser maiúscula:

```
class Ponto:
    def __init__(self, x = 0, y = 0):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

class Retangulo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.base = int(input("Digite a o valor da base(entre 1 1000): "))
        self.altura = int(input("Digite a o valor da altura(entre 1 1000): "))

    def centro(self,ponto):
        ponto.x = self.base / 2
        ponto.y = self.altura / 2
```

E usar assim:

```
retangulo = Retangulo()
ponto = Ponto()

retangulo.centro(ponto)

print(ponto.x, ponto.y)
```

<kbd>[Ver **DEMO**](https://repl.it/DQCs)</kbd>